# call c# method with parameters from js ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, parameters

when calling a c# method from js ajax I am getting 404 error on console

I tried following ways to send data to c# method

```
data: '{ name: "test" }'
data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': 1234 }),

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/system/AddCertificateFromStore",       
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{ name: "divya" }',
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    }
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json'
```

C#  method is something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddCertificateFromStore(string CertificateName)
{
    // Make the web request
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    return response;
}
```

Would like to send the parameters to C# method correctly so that it is being called from js ajax

Comment: What happens when you visit `/api/system/AddCertificateFromStore` in your browser?

Comment: You have passed parameter name and in your method parameter is CertificateName

Comment: Also, your javascript code is invalid you have excess `}`

Comment: HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:15899/api/system/AddCertificateFromStore..this is the error I am getting on browser console..

Comment: ok, so the first part of your problem is that your c# script doesn't work. Are you sure that you have the correct path / routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a FromBody decorador in your C# Action

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddCertificateFromStore([FromBody] string CertificateName)
        {

Comment: Accept this answer if solved your problem it will help others

Comment: it is now calling the method(able to hit break point in C#) but still not passing the string correctly

Comment: When you pass a string parameter with a [FromBody] decorator, you are telling the Web API to read the body content as raw string. So, if you want to access the string from de body you should simply pass it as a raw value, like

...
type: 'POST',
    data: "divya",
...

Comment: How are you making the Ajax Request?

Comment: adding FromBody solved the issue...the problem after that was with Controller ...but as far as being able to send data FromBody in C# Action helped...